# is there a way to get a UIView's frame (create in storyboard) in code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I createa a `UIView` in the storyboard, and want to add some inner shadow to this view. I also created an `IBoutlet` to this view. Is there any way to get view's frame?

```
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(display.frame.height)
}
```

error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Calculator.ViewController 0x7fba77608cd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key screen.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d7a2b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109cd5141 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d7a2a59 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x00000001097eb00b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
4   UIKit                               0x000000010b09e994 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
5   UIKit                               0x000000010b30ba09 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d748e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269
7   UIKit                               0x000000010b30a3bf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
8   UIKit                               0x000000010b0a4fc3 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
9   UIKit                               0x000000010b0a58d9 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
10  UIKit                               0x000000010b0a5c0a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
11  UIKit                               0x000000010b0a645a -[UIViewController view] + 27
12  UIKit                               0x000000010af6e98a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 65
13  UIKit                               0x000000010af6f070 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
14  UIKit                               0x000000010af81ebe -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
15  UIKit                               0x000000010aefb37f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4346
16  UIKit                               0x000000010af015e4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1709
17  UIKit                               0x000000010aefe7f3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111b715f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111b7146d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111b717f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d748c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d72e0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d72d5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d72d016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
25  UIKit                               0x000000010aefd08f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
26  UIKit                               0x000000010af03134 UIApplicationMain + 159
27  Calculator                          0x00000001096fa327 main + 55
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e74265d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

help appreciated

Comment: display.superview?.frame

Comment: also lemme know what does your print(display.frame) prints..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saying its a view but you have drawn an `IBOutlet` of `UILabel`.
Also `yourView.frame` will definitely give you the frame.
Also try deleting the previous outlet and redraw it.

Comment: it just broken.. when I called print(mylabel.frame)

Comment: have you checked that your outlet is drawn properly?

Comment: Also lemme know where have you written this print statement?

Comment: Click on your label and verify that is installed from the identity inspector.

Comment: check that your view controller is having the right class or not

Comment: Also make sure you have not edited or renamed your label's name..In that case also it gives you error..Moreover, you can just delete and redraw your outlet and then print.

Comment: thanks ... redraw all the outlet and reopen Xcode then it work fine, through get the wrong way

Comment: Great..Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You have added an outlet for a `UILabel`, but stil the same there to get the frame `display.frame`. Add an outlet to your view instead if you want that and then just `view.frame`.

It dosen't matter if it´s a view created in your storyboard or programmatically, you can always get the frame by:

```
view.frame
```

But if you specially want the frame that you have created in your Storyboard then you need to create an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: yes I create a IBoutlet and when calling the print(myView.frame) it broken

Comment: Do you have a round black dot to the left of your outlet?

Comment: yes I control drag from storyboard.. update the error message

Comment: Remove all outlets you have now from your code and right click on all elements that you have created outlets from and then recreate them.

Comment: thanks ... redraw all the outlet and reopen Xcode then it work fine, through get the wrong way